# Specific numeric numbers on single custom field

Tags: php, joomla, custom-component, number-formatting

i have made an custom field from Joomla component Vik Rent Cars, the id of the custom field is "vrcf13". 
How can i made it only accept 8 numeric numbers on it?

The code is:

```
<table class="vrccustomfields">
    <?php
    $currentUser = JFactory::getUser();
    $juseremail = !empty($currentUser->email) ? $currentUser->email : "";
    foreach ($cfields as $cf) {
        if (intval($cf['required']) == 1) {
            $isreq = "<span class=\"vrcrequired\"><sup>*</sup></span> ";
        } else {
            $isreq = "";
        }
        if (!empty ($cf['poplink'])) {
            $fname = "<a href=\"" . $cf['poplink'] . "\" id=\"vrcf" . $cf['id'] . "\" rel=\"{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 750, y: 600}}\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"modal\">" . JText :: _($cf['name']) . "</a>";
            } else { 
            $fname = "<span id=\"vrcf" . $cf['id'] . "\">" . JText :: _($cf['name']) . "</span>";
                            }
        if ($cf['type'] == "text") {
            $textmailval = intval($cf['isemail']) == 1 ? $juseremail : "";
        ?>
                    <tr><td align="right"><?php echo $isreq; ?><?php echo $fname; ?> </td><td><input type="text" name="vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $textmailval; ?>" size="40" class="vrcinput"/></td></tr>
        <?php

        }elseif ($cf['type'] == "textarea") {
        ?>
                    <tr><td valign="top" align="right"><?php echo $isreq; ?><?php echo $fname; ?> </td><td><textarea name="vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>" rows="5" cols="30" class="vrctextarea"></textarea></td></tr>
        <?php

        }elseif ($cf['type'] == "date") {
        ?>
                    <tr><td valign="top" align="right"><?php echo $isreq; ?><?php echo $fname; ?> </td><td><?php echo JHTML::_('calendar', '', 'vrcf'.$cf['id'], 'vrcf'.$cf['id'].'date', $nowdf, array('class'=>'vrcinput', 'size'=>'10',  'maxlength'=>'19')); ?></td></tr>
        <?php

        }elseif ($cf['type'] == "select") {
            $answ = explode(";;__;;", $cf['choose']);
            $wcfsel = "<select name=\"vrcf" . $cf['id'] . "\">\n";
            foreach ($answ as $aw) {
                if (!empty ($aw)) {
                    $wcfsel .= "<option value=\"" . $aw . "\">" . $aw . "</option>\n";
                }
            }
            $wcfsel .= "</select>\n";
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking to prevent a user from entering anything non-numeric and greater than 8 characters in to a text field. This can be achieved using Javascript. This assumes you have jQuery available.

```
$(function() {
    $("#number").keydown(function(key) {
        // This will only ensure the key pressed is a number (excludes the numpad)
        if(key.keyCode < 48 || key.keyCode > 57) {
            return false;
        }                                                         
        // Prevent more than 8 insertions
        if($(this).val().length > 8) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned in the comments this will only ensure a numeric key is pressed and does not cater for the numpad. It would also prevent the user from deleting etc. You can hunt down a full list of [keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) you would look to allow.

An alternative to using JS would be to check the value server side after submission. You could use PHP's [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) flag along with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: Okay thanks :) but how can i relate it to only "vrcf13" text field?

Comment: I don't know what that means because your code has no mention of `vrcf13`. I assume that's your HTML id? If so, replace `$("#number")` with `$("#vrcf13")` from my example

Comment: Thanks :D where do i but the code in my code?

Comment: Can i ude the code to multiple text fields?

Comment: Of course, `$("#firstInput #secondInput") {}`

Comment: i have this working code right now:

Comment: ?><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {var myfield = document.vrc.vrcf13;
jQuery(myfield).keydown(function(key) {
// This will only ensure the key pressed is a number (excludes the numpad)if(key.keyCode < 48 || key.keyCode > 57) {} 
// Prevent more than 8 insertions   if(jQuery(this).val().length > 8) {
alert('Kørekort nr skal ikke være mindre/større end 8 ord');// I have added here return jQuery(myfield).val(''); }
});});
function checkvrcFields(){
var vrvar = document.vrc;
<?php

Comment: I want "vrcf10" also to only accept 10 nummeric words, and make another alert statement for it, how can i do that? :)

Comment: This is scope for a new question